# variable can not be found after try block

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to process text from a user entered file when compiled the scanner in cannot be found. I am assuming it is being caught. what can I do to make this work?

```
String namef = getf.nextLine();
File inPut = new File(namef);

try { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inPut);                            
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("file not found");
}

while(in.hasNextLine()) {  // process file
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String pLine = parse(count,  namef);
}
```

Comment: Do you know something about "variable scopes"? If not, look it up.

Comment: `in` is only available inside the `try{}` scope. So move the `while` loop also into that block

Answer (score 2):

@Tom is right. You must declare the scanner outside the try block.

```
     String namef = getf.nextLine();
     Scanner in = new Scanner();  

     File inPut = new File(namef);                                    
     try
     { 
       in = new Scanner(inPut);  
       while(in.hasNextLine())       // process file
       {
         String line = in.nextLine();
         String pLine = parse(count,  namef);
       }                          
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {
       System.out.println("file not found");
     }
```

Comment: The solution is fragile. If the file is not found this code would produce a `NullPointerException`. Therefore it is best to move the while loop into the try block (where its execution is skipped if file is not found). Also the closing of the stream is missing. An elegant solution to that would be a try with resources `try (Scanner in = new Scanner(inPut)) {...` which automatically closes the stream after the try block.

Comment: Thanks for the information guys I really appreciate it

Comment: As I pointed out: with `try (Scanner in = new Scanner(inPut)) {...}` (Java8) the compiler takes care of closing. And with this code the declaration could also be inside the try block (although try-with-resources is the better way).